# Passing php variable values to javascript function

Tags: php, javascript

I'm passing PHP variable value like this:

```
<input type="button" name="delete" value="Remove" onclick="del(<?echo $arr1[0]?>);"/>
```

`del()` is a Javascript function and Eg:`$arr1[0]=234-675-90` the value of $arr1[0] is obtained from MYSQL database and its data-type in mysql is varchar.

I'm fetching value using mysql_query.

The problem I'm facing is that when value is passed to JavaScript function it takes it wrongly(eg:instead of 234-675-99 as -876).Is there any casting is to be done to pass value from PHP to JavaScript?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should pass the value as string:

```
<input type="button" name="delete" value="Remove" onclick="del('<?echo $arr1[0]?>');"/>
```

Comment: Why do that manually and possibly break if the string contains quotes when you can let `json_encode()` do it for you in a way that never breaks?

Comment: Naturally, that depends on the data format. What's been given in the question is a simple digits-and-dashes string id.

Comment: On a side-note, `json_encode()` will break the code in this particular case, since the string will be escaped using double-quotes (`"`), while apostrophes (`'`) should be used here instead. The HTML will be broken otherwise.

Comment: Do I need to install any package to use json_encode()?Because I tried earlier with json_encode but the call to javascript function did not happen.

Comment: That is exactly what I said in the previous comment: `json_encode()` will break your HTML, since you cannot have double-quotes inside a double-quoted attribute value. To avoid the breakage while still using `json_encode()`, you need to use apostrophes around the onclick value. Using ThiefMaster's solution, `... onclick='del(<?=htmlspecialchars(json_encode($arr1[0]))?>);'...`

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov: That's why I used `htmlspecialchars`, too.

Comment: @ThiefMaster: fair point, even though the resulting HTML is not too readable: `onclick="del(&quot;foo-bar&quot;)"`. That might or might not be a problem for the developer :)

Answer (score 2):

Use `json_encode()` to convert the value into value JavaScript:

```
<input type="button" name="delete" value="Remove" onclick="del(<?=htmlspecialchars(json_encode($arr1[0]))?>);"/>
```